# Implementing Ctrl, Alt, Shift, Delete keys in Keyboard XML

Tags: android, keyboard-events

I'm trying to code a simple keyboard and want to implement the above mentioned 4 keys. In my `keyboard.xml` file, I've been defining the layout like this -

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="40dp"
    >
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="9" android:keyLabel="↹" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="126,96" android:keyLabel="~`"/>
        <Key android:codes="95,45" android:keyLabel="_-"/>
        <Key android:codes="43,61" android:keyLabel="+="/>
        <Key android:codes="123,91" android:keyLabel="{["/>
    ...
```

I've been using ASCII codes inside `android:codes`. But I'm not sure what to do with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys. I have used `-5` for <kbd>Backspace</kbd> as found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html). But not sure how to implement the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

Are `KEYCODE_ALT` and `KEYCODE_SHIFT` the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>? And I'm pretty much stuck with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key as I can't find any reference to it in the doc. What silly thing am I missing?

**Edit**: If someone could throw in some pointers about the arrow keys, that'd be helpful too.